# Have html select always show same option

Tags: html

I want my `select` element to always show the same Text, no matter which option is selected. How would i do that?

```html
<select>
  <option defaultValue disabled>
    Add library
  </option>
  <option value="code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js">
    JQuery 3.1.0
  </option>
  <option value="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4/lodash.min.js">
    lodash 4.x
  </option>
  <option value="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.1.14/require.js">
    RequireJS
  </option>
</select>
```

Comment: What does "show the same Text" mean?

Comment: Why not try using a dropdown instead of a select?

Comment: Why don't you name all your options the same `Text` - then your goal would be accomplished :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just take the initial value and store it in a variable. And then, whenever the `change` event on select is called re-assign the previous value to the select.

```js
var select = document.querySelector('select');
var value = select.value;

select.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
  select.value = value;
  console.log('changed');
});
```

```html
<select>
  <option defaultValue disabled>
    Add library
  </option>
  <option value="code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js">
    JQuery 3.1.0
  </option>
  <option value="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4/lodash.min.js">
    lodash 4.x
  </option>
  <option value="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.1.14/require.js">
    RequireJS
  </option>
</select>
```

Comment: This basically breaks the select. I don't see why you would ever want this code?

Comment: *To be or not to be that's the question*